# Ruby on Rails, Prawn - Repairing a corrupt PDF in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I'm using the Prawn gem (v 0.12.0, we can't use 2.0.0 because of compatibility issues) in a Ruby on Rails project. A user uploaded a PDF that they got directly from an official government website, so this is a PDF that we will have to handle for other users as well, but it is corrupt and crashes when Prawn tries to render it as a string. You can find the PDF in the "Certificate of Rent Paid" link on [this page](http://www.revenue.state.mn.us/individuals/prop_tax_refund/Pages/Certificate_of_Rent_Paid_%28CRP%29_Information_for_Landlords.aspx).

The error I'm getting with this PDF:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass:
```

And it's coming from this method in our Prawn gem:

```
def finalize
  if dictionary.data[:Contents].is_a?(Array)
    dictionary.data[:Contents].each do |stream|
      stream.compress_stream if document.compression_enabled?
      stream.data[:Length] = stream.stream.size    # THIS LINE!!!
    end
  else
    content.compress_stream if document.compression_enabled?
    content.data[:Length] = content.stream.size    # IT DOESN'T GET TO THIS
  end
end
```

I'm stuck. The only tools I've been able to find through my searches to "fix" PDFs are Adobe Acrobat and PDFtk. PDFtk can be used in a server, but it's only for Windows and our server is running on a Linux server. I can't find any gems or any way around it. I was also able to "fix" the PDF by "Saving as PDF" from Google Chrome (v41) on a Mac (neither Windows nor Ubuntu Google Chrome worked). I want to be able to "fix" the PDF from within my Rails project though. Any thoughts/suggestions?

**[EDIT]** Using Ghostscript from the command line worked for me. This line: `gs -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress crp_14.pdf`, "fixed" the PDF. Looking into the RGhost gem now to see if I can do the same thing from within a controller or model.

Answer (score 0):

After Prawn dropped template support, I wrote a Ruby native gem called [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf).

I can't test it with your file, but you might be able to load the PDF using the gem, render it to a string (or temporary file) and reload within Prawn.

OR, maybe it could help you move on to Prawn 2.0 (you can create new PDF data with Prawn and stamp it over an existing file with [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf)).

It's just a thought, don't kill me if it doesn't work ;-)

Good luck!